# Difference between dates between corresponding rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is the example of a sample pandas dataframe. I am trying to find the difference between the dates in the two rows (with the first row as the base):

```
PH_number   date        Type
H09879721   2018-05-01  AccountHolder
H09879731   2018-06-22  AccountHolder
```

If the difference between two dates is within 90 days, then those two rows should be added to a new pandas dataframe. The `date` column is of type `object`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.diff()`:

```
df.date.diff()<=pd.Timedelta(90,'d')

0    False
1     True
Name: date, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert `date` column to `datetime64[ns]` data type using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwiui_eGtdTeAhVGWisKHe-kCrMQFjAAegQICRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fstable%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.to_datetime.html&usg=AOvVaw1Arlz9KbP1nOln9DAQPZLq) and then subtract as given:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

#if comparing with only 1st row
mask = (df['date']-df.loc[0,'date']).dt.days<=90
# alternative mask = (df['date']-df.loc[0,'date']).dt.days.le(90)

#if comparing with immediate rows.
mask = df['date'].diff().dt.days<=90
# alternative mask = df['date'].diff().dt.days.le(90)

df1 = df.loc[mask,:] #gives you required rows with all columns
```